# Unable to generate the cron expression using cron-utils

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using [cron-utils](http://cron-utils.com) jar for generating cron expression

`0 0 8 ? 1/1 5#3 *`

3rd Thursday of every month at 8 o' clock

**Below is my code for above expression:**

```java
CronBuilder withMonth = CronBuilder.cron(
      CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(CronType.QUARTZ)
).withYear(always()).withDoM(QuestionMark.questionMark())
.withMonth(on(3, SpecialChar.HASH));

withMonth.withDoW(on(5)).withHour(on(8)).withMinute(on(0)).withSecond(on(0));
    
Cron instance = withMonth.instance();
System.out.println(instance.asString());
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
value missing for a#b cron expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found solution

```
.withDoW(on(NUM_DAY_WEEK,SpecialChar.HASH, NUM_DAY_MONTH);
```

it will generate like 5#3

Comment: You may accept your own answer so your question doesn't show up as "unanswered" anymore.